# How do I get Selenium 2 webdriver to work with Nightly (Firefox 64 bit)

Tags: selenium-webdriver, testng

I'm looking to execute a Selenium 2 test against the Nightly browser (FireFox 64bit). It records just fine with the Selenium IDE (v1.8.1).  And it also plays back just fine using using the IDE.  I then export the code to TestNG format.  By the way I've loaded up the Webdriver Backed plugin so it exports WebDriver code for the Selenium 2 version.  The problem I'm having is that when I export the code to TestNG format (Java) and execute it, the asserts never find the text on the screen.  It executes fine so its not that the code didn't convert.  It just seems to be something with the asserts.  If I play it from the IDE plugin it finds it the text and asserts just fine, however as soon as it executes in Java it fails all the assertions.  Any ideas to what might be going on.  My code is below.  Thanks much!

```
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverBackedSelenium;
import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver;
import org.testng.annotations.AfterMethod;
import org.testng.annotations.BeforeMethod;
import org.testng.annotations.Test;
import static junit.framework.Assert.*;

import com.thoughtworks.selenium.Selenium;

public class TestWithConfig {

    WebDriver driver;
    Selenium selenium;

    @BeforeMethod
    public void startSelenium() {
        driver = new FirefoxDriver();
        selenium = new WebDriverBackedSelenium(driver,
                "http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Main_Page");
    }

    @AfterMethod
    public void stopSelenium() {
        driver.close();
    }

    @Test
    public void testTest() {
        selenium.setSpeed("600");
        selenium.open("/wiki/Main_Page");
        assertTrue("face not found",selenium.isTextPresent("face"));
        selenium.click("link=Contents");
        selenium.waitForPageToLoad("30000");
        assertTrue("Below not found",selenium.isTextPresent("Below"));
        selenium.click("link=Toolbox");
        selenium.click("link=What links here");
        selenium.waitForPageToLoad("30000");
        assertTrue("Pages not found",selenium.isTextPresent("Pages that link to"));
        selenium.click("link=exact:Talk:Wine");
        selenium.waitForPageToLoad("30000");
        assertTrue("Some not found",selenium.isTextPresent("Some"));
    }

}
```

Comment: What happens if you either a) downgrade Firefox and re-run the test and b) try with a different driver?

Comment: I've tried loading up the 3.6 version but it fails to come up.  Also I'm trying to be as recent as possible so that the testing is relevant.  My requirement is to use the most recent version of FF as possible.  

For your second suggestion, what other driver would you suggest?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since your using selenium 2 and webdriver, Assert's work a little different. I can see that you using the WebDriverBackedSelenium. However keep in mind. That's not selenium2. That is just a way to ease into selenium 2. I would use something like this.

```
WebElement tooltip = driver.findElement(By.xpath("the xpath of the element"));

assertNotNull("Name:","IP Address:",tooltip);
```

What I'm doing here is. i'm looking for a tooltip.inside that tooltip, there are two main labels that stay the same: Name and IP Address:. So I'm testing to see if those words exists or not in the tool tip. The output should be Name: IP Address:. That tells me the answer is true.

Comment: Sounds like a good solution.  I, however, have a team that would love to use the Selenium IDE Firefox Plugin to record their scripts.  If I remember right the scripts don't really translate to this type of code.  I would probably end up coding all of my scripts by hand.  Is this correct?

Comment: Accepting this answer.  If anyone does know if there is a good driver that also works closely w/the Selenium IDE, it would be great.  For the time being I'll use the suggestion given here.

Comment: I am confused with the syntax: assertNotNull("Name:","IP Address:",tooltip); As I know there are 2 parameters as: assertNotNull(tooltip, "Name:"); Please correct me if I am wrong